# Eigen generic function to handle different data types

Tags: eigen

I am trying to write a generic function that receives a `DenseBase<Derived>` parameter like this:

```
template<class Derived>
MatrixXd Math::gradient(const DenseBase<Derived> &y, const Dimension dimension)
{
    ...
    Derived v = dimension == COLUMNS ? y.derived() : y.derived().transpose();
    ...
}
```

I'm having an error when I call the function in this manner:

`const VectorXd g = Math::gradient(curve/ peak);`

The `curve/ peak` expression returns a `CwiseBinaryOp` type, which becomes the `Derived` type of the `Math::gradient` templated function.

However, the `y.derived().transpose()` expression returns a `Transpose<MatrixType>` which yields a compilation error due to the different data type with respect to the `CwiseBinaryOp`

I know I can call the `Math::gradient` function previously storing the `curve/ peak` in a `VectorXd` to solve the problem, however, how can I write the function to handle this different datatypes?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Could you elaborate on why you need to explicitly store the transpose of `y`? What is `Dimension dimension`? Is it known at compile-time? (Same question for `COLUMNS`) If you want to be generic, why do you return a `MatrixXd`?

Comment: Ok, thank you for the advice. The function `Math::gradient` computes the numerical gradient of each "signal" stored in the `y` variable (`Matrix` or `Array` object, for that reason I used `DenseBase<Derived>` type). The default behavior assumes that signals are stored in columns, i.e. `y` is a "matrix" of N signals of D dimensions each signal. However, the `Dimension` variable allows the user to specify if the signals are stored in `ROWS` or `COLUMNS` of the `y` variable. For that reason, I need to `tanspose` the `y` variable in case of the user provided the signals stored in ROWS.

Comment: Finally, I always return a `MatrixXd` because the numerical gradient of a signal performs a convolution of each signal with a kernel that (in most cases) produces floating point results. Each `COLUMN` (or `ROW`) of the output `MatrixXd` corresponds to the gradient of its respective signal in the input `y`. Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: Would it be possible to pass the dimension at compile time? This way you could use `std::conditional_t<Dim==COLUMNS,const Derived::PlainObject&, Transpose<const Derived::PlainObject> > v(y.derived());`

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found a solution to my own question (sorry for the poor explanation of the problem).

By using the `eval()` method of the `DenseBase<Derived>` variable `y`, Eigen resolves the "intermediate" expression types, such as the `CwiseBinaryOp` or the `Transpose<MatrixType>` in my particular case, to a `PlainObject` variable type.

So a possible solution could be:

```
template<class Derived>
MatrixXd Math::gradient(const DenseBase<Derived> &y, const Dimension dimension)
{
    ...
    typename Derived::PlainObject v = dimension == COLUMNS ? y.derived().eval() : y.derived().transpose().eval();
    ...
}
```

Thank you very much for your attention

Comment: That won't work, e.g., for `Derived = Matrix<double, 3,2>`

Comment: Right. For fixed size matrices/arrays it does not work. Any idea? Thank you very much.

Comment: I don't see a good solution, unless you know `dimension == COLUMNS` at compile time. But from the little information you provide, I don't know if you actually need to store `v`.